# How to mathematically describe a graph convolutional network architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, graph-neural-network

I have developed a GCN architecture with 3 different inputs, related to 3 different blocks of layers. After that, the outputs of those layers are concatenated. And after that, the architecture has a fully connected layer. I detail the architecture involves:

Input block (there are three of these, independent from each other):
Graph convolutional layer
Tanh function
global_max_pool layer

Concatenation, which concatenates the results of these three input blocks

Fully connected layer

How can I provide a mathematical description of this architecture (in functional style), like the description provided on page 23 of the network represented in figur2 2.1 of this text?
https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/18264/Nguyen_Duy.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y